# Paper get rejected despite positive recommendations from both reviewers

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, rejection

I have submitted a paper to an IEEE conference before this. I received a rejection today despite the fact that, both reviewers recommend to accept my paper.

The reason for rejection is not mentioned at all in the email. I try to analyze the reason and from my point of view:

1. The paper is not out of the conference's scope. If my paper is out of scope, it should be rejected at the first place without sending out to be reviewed.
2. Both reviewers recommend to accept my paper.
3. The conference should have not received too many papers. This is because the deadline for submission has just been extended to 10 Nov. In other words, they continue to accept submission of papers at this point.

I was really surprise after I read the following email:

> Dear xxx:
>
> Unfortunately, your paper xxx for xxx has not been accepted for
>   publication. We hope that you will find the reviews useful when
>   revising your paper.
>
> The reviews are below or can be found at xxx.
>
> ======= Review 1 =======
>
> *** Originality: New or Novel contribution Strong Accept (10)
>
> *** Technical Contribution: Technical/Scientific Contribution, also consider papers that contributes to development of applications.
>   Accept (8)
>
> *** Significance of Topic: Relating to knowledge contribution & conference scope (relevant to Science, Engineering & Technology)
>   Strong Accept (10)
>
> *** Presentation: Clarity and Organisation of Content (Includes Language & Formatting) Accept (8)
>
> *** Recommendation: Overall view and recommendation Strong Accept (10)
>
> *** Detailed comments: What are the major issues addressed in the paper? Do you consider them important? What are the major reasons to
>   accept or reject the paper? Comment on the degree of novelty,
>   creativity and technical depth in the paper.[Be brief.]
>
> Please provide detailed comments that will be helpful to the TPC for
>   assessing the paper, as well as feedback to the authors.
>
> The paper was reporting an original findings by the authors based on
>   their simulation. xxx. I reckon it is of sufficient quality for the
>   conference.
>
> ======= Review 2 =======
>
> *** Originality: New or Novel contribution Accept (8)
>
> *** Technical Contribution: Technical/Scientific Contribution, also consider papers that contributes to development of applications.
>   Accept (8)
>
> *** Significance of Topic: Relating to knowledge contribution & conference scope (relevant to Science, Engineering & Technology)
>   Accept (8)
>
> *** Presentation: Clarity and Organisation of Content (Includes Language & Formatting) Accept (8)
>
> *** Recommendation: Overall view and recommendation Accept (8)
>
> *** Detailed comments: What are the major issues addressed in the paper? Do you consider them important? What are the major reasons to
>   accept or reject the paper? Comment on the degree of novelty,
>   creativity and technical depth in the paper.[Be brief.]
>
> Please provide detailed comments that will be helpful to the TPC for
>   assessing the paper, as well as feedback to the authors.
>
> Good paper and well written. Easy to understand. xxx.

I replaced some of the reviewers' comments with 'xxx' because it will reveal my unpublished works. Please believe me when I say they are all positive.

Has someone been in this situation before? What is the possible reasons for rejection?

Comment: There could be political reasons.  A senior researcher I know had an abstract rejected to a ESA conference because it was about a satellite instrument proposed to ESA, and it was apparently ESAs policy to not host any presentations about proposed instruments.

Comment: It might just have been that they got very many papers with Accept >= 9...

Comment: @gerrit, my work is no way related to any political issue.

Comment: You could ask why it was rejected.  You may or may not get a useful reply.

Comment: @vonbrand they have recently extended the deadline for submission. In other words, they continue to accept submission at this point.

Comment: I do not understand how your conference paper got rejected, before the submission deadline. Are you sure that the submission deadline has been extended? Reviews are usually starting after the submission deadline has expired.

Comment: @Alexandros, the deadline for submission was first on 31/10. On 1/11, they extended it to 10/11. I received a decision on 3/11.

Comment: You got a decision after 3 days in review? This does not sound like a "real" conference to me.

Comment: Exactly like @ff524 said. This is not a real conference, receiving a decision in 3 days. Be glad that it was rejected and you were saved from the embarrassment to withdraw the paper.

Comment: @ff524 It is an IEEE conference. All accepted papers will be indexed in scopus.

Comment: @W.Loon doesn't mean it's any good

Comment: It may be that other reviewers would give it a 3. It may be that it was a 10, and they had room for two, and not yours. Get over it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**This is a perfectly possible result.**  The reviewers' recommendations are just that: recommendations.  The conference's scientific committee has the ultimate say over whether a paper is accepted, and they do not always follow reviewers' recommendations.

There may be quite legitimate reasons for a paper to be rejected despite positive reviews.  For example:

- **There might be an abundance of high quality submissions on the particular topic you submitted on** (even if the deadline was extended because they didn't get enough submissions in other areas).
- **There still could be a scope issue.**  Yes, a paper that is clearly out of scope should be rejected before it goes to review.  However, if the committee felt it was at the margins of acceptable scope, they might send it to review but ultimately reject it because the reviewers' comments weren't sufficient to overcome the scope problem.
- **The conference reviewers were generous**.  It is hard to interpret the meaning of the reviewers' scores without seeing the distribution of all scores.  It is possible that the reviewers were really "nice" and scores tended to be high for everyone.  It is quite difficult for many people to give a negative decision when they know that someone else is going to see the result and be affected by it, so scores can tend toward the positive, and rejection recommendations may be rare.
- **There was some kind of rule preventing them from accepting it** (This should have led to rejection before review, but it could have been missed.  Of course, they also should have told you the reason if this were the case).

**You are correct, however, that this is a fairly unusual decision.**  I think you ought to follow up and ask for clarification.  It would be helpful for you to know the reason for rejection, and there is always the chance that there was some kind of clerical error, as well.

Answer (score 2):

As *ff524* says in a comment, the conference seems to be of a dubious nature, and it might be better not to want to publish there at all. Here are some of the red flags, but note that it is entirely possible for a number of excellent conferences to trigger one or more of them. It's just that all of them together suggest that some background checking is called for.

> "The paper was reporting an original findings by the authors based on their simulation. xxx. I reckon it is of sufficient quality for the conference."

"was reporting" and "an original findings" reveals extremely poor English, and poor English is highly correlated with crackpot publications. "reckon" is quite informal and has not much place in a review, in my opinion.

> "Good paper and well written. Easy to understand. xxx."

Like the other review, this one does not sound genuine.

> The conference should have not received too many papers. This is because the deadline for submission has just been extended to 10 Nov. In other words, they continue to accept submission of papers at this point.

The best well-established CS conferences (especially the main ones rather than the smaller conferences with narrow focus) usually receive too many papers and end up rejecting even papers they deem a good fit for the conference simply because there are too many excellent submissions, and they usually do not arbitrarily extend deadline for submission just like that either.

> the deadline for submission was first on 31/10. On 1/11, they extended it to 10/11. I received a decision on 3/11

As *ff524* said, this implies that they reviewed your paper within 3 days. It's not impossible but just another tiny bell goes off, since there are already some ringing.

> They reject your paper despite reviewers recommending acceptance but seem to be looking for more.

If you exclude the possibilities mentioned by *dan1111*, then this would be a warning sign.

At the very least, if you want to publish at a good conference, you had better be careful and check this one out thoroughly.

Comment: *Good conferences usually receive too many papers and usually do not arbitrarily extend deadline for submission just like that.* - That's not true in a general sense. In my field, there are plenty of good conferences that routinely extend submission deadlines.

Comment: @ff524: I see. Well I just took a look at the related question on deadlines at http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17178/15940. It seems people do seem to agree that the top CS conferences generally do not move their deadlines. So can you name some that do?

Comment: In the question you link to the OP says "I won't overestimate if I said 80% of the conferences (I have followed) have this attitude." The first answer is from someone in theoretical computer science, who says in his field it's not like that. There's a comment on that answer from someone in software engineering saying "80% is about right in my field." In my field, telecommunications, extensions are common. You can't really generalize across fields, which is why I said "That's not true in a general sense." (Also "top" is not the same thing as "good.")

Comment: @ff524: I didn't say I want to generalize. By "good" I meant "top", if that is causing the misunderstanding, so I'll edit my answer to reflect that. The reason I was thinking of top conferences is because the asker explicitly gave the impression that he/she believes his/her work to be top quality, and so shouldn't be aiming for anything less.

Comment: @user21820 i am sorry if any of my words lead to your misunderstanding. I have NEVER said that my work is of top quality. Throughout my entire posts, I just asked for the possible reasons for rejection despite good recommendations from both reviewers.

Comment: There are many conferences that publish excellent, high-quality work in certain areas of CS, that extend submission deadlines. (Especially smaller, more focused conferences whose scope is narrow.) So I still disagree with your statement. If you don't mean it as a general statement, you should qualify it to explain when it applies and when it doesn't.

Comment: @W.Loon: Then it's entirely possible that yours is one of too many good submissions and they had no choice but to accept only some. However, my other points still stand. It would be far easier for others to guess what happened if you mentioned which conference it was, but if you don't want to then you'll have to check it on your own. If it is listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_computer_science_conferences&oldid=682397521, then you have much less to worry about.

Comment: @ff524: Alright.. the larger well-established ones.. There are too many exceptions to every rule-of-thumb. In any case that factor was a small one, but together with the other factors they don't make for a very comfortable feeling.

Comment: Even large, well-established, high-quality conferences may extend submission deadlines. [Here's a recent example](http://icc2016.ieee-icc.org) of one such conference in my field. Your statement is simply not accurate, so I think you should remove it.

Comment: @ff524: Hmm but I did say "usually" from the beginning. Are you so sure that it is the norm for those conferences to extend deadlines? It doesn't seem so to me. If you show me that it's the norm in some areas I'll surely remove my claim, though it is one of the factors that add to the picture.

Comment: I'm not really that motivated to collect links to submission extension announcements from a dozen conferences in my field to prove a point to a stranger on the Internet. If you don't want to remove it, it's your decision. I just think it would be a shame for someone to come across this, read this answer, and think "Hmmm... there must be something wrong with this conference if it keeps extending the deadline!" when that might in fact be perfectly normal and not at all a bad sign in some sub-fields.

Comment: @ff524: Alright I'll add a note that it may be perfectly normal.

Comment: @ff524: Personally, though, if a conference has a **habit** of extending the deadline for no good reason, it **is indeed** a bad sign and I won't want to publish there.

Comment: @dan1111: Well my viewpoint is that it is better to be cautious and find out the reasons for each of the points I raise. You lose nothing by doing some checking to make sure you know what you're getting into, don't you think?

Comment: It is important to check whether a conference is any good, but the main things I would do for this are: ask other experts in the field, see who is speaking at the conference, see who sponsors it, and read information about it.  I think it is pointless to speculate based on a very limited set of evidence.

Comment: -1: Competence in English is not a prerequisite for competence in any STEM technical field. And lots of crackpot papers are written in perfect English. And IEEE conferences generally are not of a dubious nature.

Comment: @PeterShor: Your last sentence is irrelevant, because we are not discussing the **average** IEEE conference but rather the **specific** one in question. https://www.nature.com/news/publishers-withdraw-more-than-120-gibberish-papers-1.14763. How do you know this one is not one of them? As for competence in English, I said it's just one factor. If you fail all of my criteria, you are **likely** to be a crackpot.

Comment: Majority of the active researchers in any STEM field are foreigners, ESL speakers. Criticizing a referee based on his/her English grammar and calling everyone cheater who collaborates with him/her suggest an extremely poor understanding of how academia works. One would call it an opinion from a crackpot scientist.:)

Comment: @Greg: I've said at least 3 times already that it is not **likely** that a legitimate scientist fails **all the factors** I listed? Of course there will be exceptions, but one would be foolish not to make further checks on the publisher. And as far as I can tell you're the first one on this page who used the word "cheater", so I don't understand why you seem to imply that I used it. I seriously hope you're not trying to misrepresent my position, given your smiley at the end... =|

Comment: @user21820 Indeed you were not clear on the language, called the publication "crackpot", which means eccentric, lunatic, crazy, insane in English. As non of these meaning make sense in the context of a conference, based on your criteria I assumed you are talking about low-quality predatory conference. Of course if you mean that the organizers and reviewers just held a huge pool party with binge drinking and orgy to go over the submission reviews, then indeed crackpot is the right word. Anyway sorry to hurt your sensibility.

Comment: @Greg: [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crackpot) says "crackpot" can be a noun referring to an person with bizarre ideas or an adjective meaning foolish or harebrained, as in "a crackpot notion". [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crackpot) agrees, saying that "crackpot" can be used for ideas. A conference's quality is dependent on the reviewers. If you cannot perform logical deductions properly, don't put words into my mouth.

Comment: @user21820: I can't help but think your comment responding to my comment is completely inconsistent. You defend yourself by saying that not being competent in English is just one factor that points to a researcher being a crackpot. Similarly, being an IEEE conference is another factor that points to a conference being of reasonable quality.

Comment: @PeterShor: I do not think my position is inconsistent, because judging anything always depends on a whole host of factors, and nothing turns on just one. Agreed, being an IEEE conference is a factor in favour of quality, **if it is randomly picked from all IEEE conferences**. We are not talking about a random one here... Are you trying to say that you **disagree** with my opening and concluding paragraphs advising the asker to make a careful background check?? If not, I don't understand what you don't get about the "beware red flags" sentiment...

Comment: I very, very strongly disagree with your proposition that if somebody speaks English poorly, they are more likely to be a crackpot. (1) It's prejudice. (2) Judging from my experience, it's not correct.

Comment: In fact, it's very close to outright racism. "This person is a foreigner, therefore his scientific opinion is more likely to be worthless."

Comment: @PeterShor: Where did I say that poor English in **ordinary speech** correlates with being a crackpot?? It's in writings that are supposed to be official. I expect any researcher who wishes to communicate in English to put some minimal effort in writing proper English, and the standard of English in the quoted 'review' was poorer than I expect. As for racism, I am not at all racist or intentionally biased. You, on the other hand, seem to wish to interpret whatever I say in the worst possible way you can dream up. Please don't be so rash in your judgement when you don't know my character.

Comment: For ***actual papers***, people who don't speak English well generally have them proofread by somebody who speaks English well and can correct errors. Do they do this for all their informal emails, conference reviews, and so forth? No! It would be way too much of a burden on their friends who speak English well. Can they fix the errors themselves by proofreading? No! They don't speak English well. Are they crackpots? Usually not.

Comment: @PeterShor: **Just 5 minutes of Google** led to [this free online grammar checker](http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar) that instantly catches both errors in the quote from the first 'review'. Are you trying to say that those people who won't put in minimal effort to learn enough to avoid such basic errors can't even spend a few minutes plus a click to help themselves?

Comment: @user21820 Or maybe they spend more time with science than being a grammar nazi in their second (or third..) language. I know many esl scientists, most of them has consistently bad English, even the ones who live in States. Curiously, they are better expressing ideas even with such bad English than many of their ‘murican colleagues....

Comment: @user21820: Have you ever tried to learn a foreign language? I have. Let me assure you that unless you are a linguistic genius, "minimal effort to learn enough to avoid such basic errors" takes an incredible amount of time and work.

Comment: @PeterShor: You're only further showing how wrong you are about me, and how you yet again make illogical deductions. Firstly, I know 2 foreign languages that are very different from English and from each other, at 2 different proficiency levels, and I am not a linguistic genius. Secondly, I gave you **an explicit website** whereby you can remove such basic errors in **English (not another language)** in less than a few minutes, which is **hardly any time and work**. You refuse to admit that I have shown how it can be done. Just leave me alone if you have nothing constructive to add.